# How to center div while keeping inside divs on same line in css?

Tags: css, html, center

I want to center the #nav div on the page.  Inside I want the other divs to stay on the same line together separated by my 10+10px margin as is so far.  I don't want the inside divs to collapse on separate lines while shrinking the page too small..

http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/789/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/789/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/789/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Take out `float:left` from the embedded `div`s
- Add `white-space:nowrap; display:inline-block;` to your container `div`

Here's modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/9e4hX/

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew I was too cluttered.  One last question.. I want to make the nav div spread across horizontally.. so the background colour seems continous..

Comment: Sure - change `display:table-cell` to `display:table` and add `text-align:center` to #nav. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kDrJL/

Answer (score 0):

Just set the #nav div to have a fixed width (the total width of the contained elements) and set display to block. Then clear your floats after the elements to keep the #nav div surrounding them.  Don't use table-cell as the display.

CSS

`#nav { display: block; width: 416px; }`

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="bark"></div>
<div id="profile"></div>
<div id="read"></div>
<div id="write"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#nav{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(77,77,77);
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/791/)

Answer (score 0):

change your container div to `display: table` not table-cell and add `margin: auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/3j5kc/

```
#nav{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgb(77,77,77);
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```